# How to properly configure lazy loading

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, .net-standard

In the view model below, I can see that `part.CountryCode` is always `null`.

I can get the data if I use `db.Parts.Include(p => p.CountryCode)`, but I would like to set up lazy loading for now. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

I'm using:

- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (2.1.4)` in a `NETStandard.Library(2.0.3)`
- UI is WPF with .NET 4.6.1

**ViewModel**

```
class PagePartsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }

    public PagePartsViewModel()
    {
        Parts = new ObservableCollection<PartViewModel>();
        var parts = StandardDatabase.Commands.GetParts();
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            Parts.Add(new PartViewModel(part));
        }
    }
}
```

**GetParts()**

```
public static List<Part> GetParts()
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        return db.Parts.ToList();
    }
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.OnConfiguring()**

```
optionsBuilder
    .UseLazyLoadingProxies()
    .UseSqlServer("Connection String");
```

**ApplicationDbContext.OnModelCreating()**

```
builder.Entity<Part>()
    .HasOne(p => p.CountryCode);
builder.Entity<CountryCode>()
    .HasAlternateKey(cc => cc.Code);
```

**Part.cs**

```
public class Part : EntityBase
{
    public string OEMNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CountryOfOrigin { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(10, 2)")]
    public decimal BellUnitCost { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(9, 3)")]
    public double Weight { get; set; }

    public virtual StockQuantity StockQuantity { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PartQuantity> PartQuantities { get; set; }

    public virtual CountryCode CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

**CountryCode.cs**

```
public class CountryCode : EntityBase
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    return db.Parts.ToList();
}
```

The `using` block disposes your dbContext once it finishes loading your parts. Lazy-loading requires the dbContext to still be alive.

Comment: Thanks Brad that makes sense - I didn't know it worked like that. Would you recommend that `Commands` implements `IDisposable` so that I can wrap `GetParts()` in a `using Commands()`?

Comment: Personally I would recommend just including any navigation properties you need ahead of time. I suggest using dependency injection and having your class accept an instance of dbContext and then scoping the lifetime of the dbContext to the lifetime of the request (I'm not sure how that works with WPF, but the dbContext lifetime shouldn't be the responsibility of your NetStandard library)

Comment: I would like to try that but I'm not sure how I can inject a .net-core DbContext into a .net-framework app